# What presentation for a local Oracle User Group?

Tags: java, presentation

I can do a presentation on a java related technology on the local Oracle User Group (OUG).
The last several times I talked about Java 7 (two or three times) and DVCS. The organizers didn't like the DVCS topic too much because it doesn't come from Oracle, but allowed it anyway.

So, please, can you propose some topics that would be:
1. trendy (optional)
2. oracle related (I prefer java related) (a must)
3. Could be presented in a 1-hour session.
4. Are not too complex. The audience is ... how to put it mildly: more DB oriented than Java oriented. Introductory lectures are perfect.

I saw a presentation on Chronon (a new debugger). This could have been the perfect presentation, but the product is not open-source and not that Oracle related.

I need something simple with a lot of value. I'm thinking for parts of (JSRs) JDK7 and JDK8, but I explained JDK7 already, and jigsaw and others from JDK8 are not clearly defined yet.

Comment: Would be better, if this was asked in programmers.stackexchange. Voting to close for migration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`invokedynamic` and its ramifications for the predominant and upcoming dynamic languages (Groovy, JRuby, Scala, Clojure, Redline Smalltalk come to mind first).

Comment: I need something that can easily be seen/presented. With easy-to-understand examples.